# How can I remove dynamically generated event handlers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

When I click the buttons, I see the console message showing that I've clicked them. When I uncheck the checkbox and then click the buttons, I expect no console messages but I still see them. Why doesn't the `removeEventListener` remove the event listener?

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');

function initialize() {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    function doSomething() {
      console.log(`You clicked on ${buttons[i].textContent}`);
    }

    if (document.querySelector('#mode').checked) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', doSomething);
    } else {
      buttons[i].removeEventListener('click', doSomething);
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#mode').addEventListener('click', initialize);
initialize();
```

```html
<input id='mode' type='checkbox' checked/>
<label for='mode'>Do something when you click</label>
<ul>
  <li><button>One</button>
  <li><button>Two</button>
  <li><button>Three</button>
  <li><button>Four</button>
```

I can't define `doSomething` outside of the for loop because I need `i` to do other stuff (not shown here for the sake of simplicity). I do need different handlers for each index.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `doSomething` is defined inside the for loop which means that every time `initialize` executes, you end up with a new function called `doSomething`. So `addEventListener` adds one function called `doSomething`, and `removeEventListener` attempts to remove a different function (also called `doSomething`). The new `doSomething` was never registered as an event listener so it can't be removed, and the old `doSomething` is out of scope so we can't reference it to remove it. Instead, you can dynamically generate the functions once and reference them in `initialize`.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');

const buttonFunctions = [];

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttonFunctions[i] = function doSomething() {
    console.log(`You clicked on ${buttons[i].textContent}`);
  }
}



function initialize() {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (document.querySelector('#mode').checked) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonFunctions[i]);
    } else {
      buttons[i].removeEventListener('click', buttonFunctions[i]);
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('#mode').addEventListener('click', initialize);
initialize();
```

```html
<input id='mode' type='checkbox' checked/>
<label for='mode'>Do something when you click</label>
<ul>
  <li><button>One</button>
  <li><button>Two</button>
  <li><button>Three</button>
  <li><button>Four</button>
```