# remove eventListener from for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to remove the event listener that I've added in for loop but it didn't work

Is there a way to do this with pure js?

```
for (let i = 0; i < drumPads.length; i++) {
    drumPads[i].addEventListener("click", func)
    function func() {
      display.innerHTML = music[i][0];
      sound.src = music[i][1];
      sound.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code that tries to remove the event listener.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71029613/how-can-i-remove-dynamically-generated-event-handlers-in-javascript/71029614#71029614

Comment: I had typed out a question to your first question you published, but your question was deleted before I could answer. I didn't want to throw away my answer so I re-asked the question (or a version of it) so I could post my answer. ☝

Comment: This question is similar to my first question, there was some problem in my first question, so I deleted it, please give me the answer of this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function `func` should be defined outside the loop.

In your code the function `func` is block scoped and hence this wont be refering to the same memory when the user enters with "on" and "off" condition.

You can pass the index and some custom data from the target to the listner function by setting [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) of the target.

```js
let drumPads = document.getElementsByClassName("drum-pads");

function Power(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < drumPads.length; i++) {
    if (a === 'on') {
      drumPads[i].dataset.index = i;
      drumPads[i].addEventListener("click", func);
    } else {
      drumPads[i].removeEventListener("click", func);
    }
  }
}

function func(e) {
  const targetIndex = e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
  console.log('Triggered listner', targetIndex);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="drum-pads">drum-pads 1</button>
  <button class="drum-pads">drum-pads 2</button>
  <button class="drum-pads">drum-pads 3</button>
  <button class="drum-pads">drum-pads 4</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="Power('on')">Toggle On</button>
  <button onclick="Power('off')">Toggle Off</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But his `func()` is a closure that references `music[i]`

Comment: @Barmar yes the function func is block scoped here and hence it wont refer to the same meory location when the function execuetes with "on" and "off" condition So to remove that dependency, the method has to be moved out of the loop to remove the closure

Comment: Can you show how to make it play the correct `music[i]` without putting it in the loop?

Comment: yes Barmar is right because i want  play the correct music[i]

Comment: @Barmar @Prince You can pass the index from the target to the listner function by adding a custom `metaData` node to your target. Donot forget to dele the same while removing click event listner. Updated the same in my code.

Comment: You should use the standard `dataset` API rather than a custom property for future-proofing.

Comment: @Barmar agreed and updated the answer.

Comment: Its working   thankyou so much